# Можно ли проверить к какому контексту относятся vao?

Tags: opengl, opengles

К примеру у меня есть несколько контекстов, в которых созданы `vao`, так вот, есть ли возможность проверить правильный ли я использую `vao` (относится ли он к текущему контексту)?

Comment: у Вас vao представлен числом которое получено от opengl?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ само собой

Comment: а сами значения пересекаются?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если контексты разные, то значения могут быть одинаковые

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> проверить правильный ли я использую vao

[`glIsVertexArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/)